# Entity Framework: Define DbSet from Query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Is there a way to define a dbset (or other iqueryable type) as a query string?

Example:

```
var myQuery = "Select * from dbo.MyTable";

var dbset = context.Set<MyTableRow>(myQuery); //Hypothetical Overload
```

So I could then go with something like

```
dbset.Where(x => x.SomeProperty == 1);
```

I am trying to dynamically set a dbset from a dynamic sql string.

Comment: You are going to want to avoid directly using a string to form a query. As long as there is a lambda conversion it should be okay, but be careful about using strings which contain user input in their raw form.

Comment: You should look into ESql: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38647/performance-of-linq-to-entities-vs-esql

Comment: @TravisJ Thanks for the mention!  The string will be safe!